# Define two operations in $V$={${i\in \mathbb N: i<2^n}$}

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$={${i\in \mathbb N: i<2^n}$}, with n fixed. Define an operation for addition and an operation for scalar multiplication so that $V$ with those operations is a vector space over $\mathbb Z_2$

I can´t think about a sum and a scalar multiplication that I can define in $V$, Can you give me a hand please? I would appreciate your help :)

Comment: Does your definition of $\mathbb N$ include 0, or not?

Comment: yes, my teacher always includes $0$

Comment: Hint:   What must the dimension of this vector space be?  Now pick a basis of that cardinality!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Notice that $|V|=2^n$. So, you want to put a structure on $V$ such that $V$ becomes isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_2}^n$. (every finite dimensional vector space over a field is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}^k$, where $k$= dimension of the vector space.)

Comment: so the sum is the same as the sum defined in the integers modulo 2?

Comment: @user128422: In $\mathbb{Z_2}^n$ sum of the vectors $(a_1,a_2,\cdots a_n)$ and $(b_1,a_2,\cdots b_n)$ is $(a_1+b_1,a_2+b_2,\cdots a_n+b_n)$ where $a_i+b_i$ is sum mod $2$.